# How get jQuery data in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I see return data in console but

```
data.results[0].address_components[4].long_name;
```

I didn't take data when is test undefined but

```
x.innerhtml = data.results[0].address_components[4].long_name;
```

I see city name.

How can I do it?

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var sonuc;
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
 // x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " +position.coords.latitude+ 
  //"<br>Longitude: "+position.coords.longitude;
  var locAPI="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+"&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxhnfV2NWg&sensor=false";
  
  $.get({
        url:locAPI,
        success:function(data){

          console.log(data);
          sonuc=data.results[0].address_components[4].long_name;// i didn' taka data

         }


         
  });

   x.innerHTML=sonuc;
   $.get("giden.php",{"city":sonuc},function(get_veri){

          $(".veri").text(get_veri) }); 
       
  //x.innerHTML=locAPI;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is.

Comment: What are you getting when you do console.log(data)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're not sure why you are able to `console.log(data)` in your `success` callback function but when you try to render the `data.results[0].address_components[4].long_name;` to your html it renders `undefined`.

The reason why this is happening is because your `success` callback is asynchronous and you are appending the `sonuc` value before the success callback get's fired. What you should do is abstract out the logic for appending `data.results[0].address_components[4].long_name;` to your html into another function. This new function should be executed in your `success` callback. This way you are only setting `x.innerHTML` once you have a successful request and have actual data.

See the code below.

```
 $.get({
    url:locAPI,
    success:function(data){
        renderWhenDataIsValid(data)
    }
});

function renderWhenDataIsValid(data){
    sonuc=data.results[0].address_components[4].long_name;
    x.innerHTML=sonuc;
    $.get("giden.php",{"city":sonuc},function(get_veri){
        $(".veri").text(get_veri) 
    });    
}
```

I've also added a working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xh3yaegd/21/) you just need to supplement your API key.